# Adobe Flash slide show not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, adobe

We are migrating our website and for some reason the slideshow on the home page has failed to load. It seems to be stuck on the first slide. We cannot seem to find the problem because the code for the Home page is the same as the dev page. Here is the code for the slideshow:

```
<div id="splash">
<script language="javascript">

if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0) {
    alert("This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js.");
} else {
    AC_FL_RunContent(
        'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0',
        'width', '980',
        'height', '215',
        'src', '/public/flash/homeSlideshow/homeSlideshow',
        'movie', '/public/flash/homeSlideshow/homeSlideshow',
        'base' , 'flash/homeSlideshow/index.jsp',
        'wmode','transparent'
        ); //end AC code
}
</script>
</div>
```

**also when you right click the production slide show options appear for Adobe. But when you do the same for the dev, it treats it like a picture

Comment: _seems to be stuck on the first slide_. Sounds like a problem in your Actionscript, not your HTML or JavaScript.

Comment: well when you right click the production slide show options appear for Adobe. But when you do the same for the dev, it treats it like a picture

Comment: What errors are you getting in your console>

Comment: ...com/public/index.jsp is running in Compatibility View because 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View' is checked.SEC7115:    :visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles were not applied to :visited. **Note these are the same errors in production

Answer (score 0):

We removed the 'index.jsp' from the last path and it worked